# Is a PBS a measuring device without observer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superposition, measurement-problem

Let a photon In superposition of v and h polarization is going through a Polarizing beam splitter PBS. If it passes, it is in h polarization on path A, otherwise is in v on path B. Let have a detector D in point x from the PBS on path A. When it clicks the state of the photon collapses to state h. But x is not the point where this happens. By moving D closer we would diminish x to 0. So the transformation from h+v state to x state occurs on the PBS itself and going through a PBS is a measurement. Secondly no observer is needed to collapse the state because collapse is in the PBS. D and observer will be always away from point 0 (PBS). Observer can look at the result later meaning for him the collapse happen say 2 days after which can not be true. Let alone he can be unexperienced and cannot read the result.

In the end my idea is that after a PBS a photon can be only in one path.

PS: There is a similar(duplicate) question on PSE but it is not answered or rather is answered without this considerations. Please if you answer that the photon is in both paths take into account my considerations and show how they are disproved.

Comment: PBS = Polarizing beam splitter?

Comment: Yes surely of course

Comment: A PBS entangles the photon's polarization with its position. It doesn't do a measurement, because you can recombine the beams (which is totally standard in practice) and see an interference pattern.

Comment: @knzhou Can you disprove my considerations? For recombination do you mean rotate one path and use an ordinary BS?